# R: Modelling Forward Growth by a Set Rate

Tags: r, loops, lapply

I am trying to forecast the growth of a population over the next five years, by a set rate: 10%, and have yet to find a solution specific to my issue on here.

I start with an empty data.frame, dim() 5x2.  I then populate the first column with years.  From there I add the population (in millions) at year 2019, like so:

```
popGrowth <- data.frame(matrix(NA,nrow=5,ncol=2))
popGrowth[,1] <- 2019:2023
colnames(popGrowth) <- c('years','population')
popGrowth[1,2] <- 10.4
```

Now is where the wheels fall off.  I have tried:

```
growth_rate <- 0.1

popGrowth$population <- sapply(seq_along(popGrowth$population), function(x){
  (x-1)*(1+growth_rate)
})
```

And it gives me a nice growth rate, but ignores the initial population.  I am definitely missing something in my growth formula.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about using `cumprod`...

```
growth_rate <- 0.1

popGrowth$population <- 10.4 * cumprod(c(1, rep((1 + growth_rate), nrow(popGrowth) - 1)))

popGrowth

  years population
1  2019   10.40000
2  2020   11.44000
3  2021   12.58400
4  2022   13.84240
5  2023   15.22664
```

Comment: It works that's for sure.  Do you mind walking me through the syntax?

Comment: @EBITDAN `cumprod(x)` is the cumulative product of the elements of `x`.  I have set `x` to be `1` followed by `(1+growth_rate)` repeated `(no of rows in dataframe) - 1` times.  So the `population` column is just the start value `10.4` times this vector.